# Is it possible to disable crafting recipes in Minecraft for certain items and not disable others?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

At the moment, I am making a map and eventually I want the player to only craft a certain item and disable them from crafting anything else possible. If I can't find a solution, I'll just make a villager to trade the crafting items. Please help! (I think you can somehow do this with knowledge books but I don't know how ***if*** that is the case)

Comment: Are you in 1.13? There it's possible by overwriting Vanilla recipes with your own recipes or just with nothing. But you would have to rewrite all your commands. Do you want a 1.13 solution?

Comment: I'm in 1.12.2 and I don't want to mess with the game's code, I just want to use commands.

Comment: Nothing with code, in 1.13 you can put recipes in data packs.

Comment: If you don't want to use 1.13, then villagers are probably actually the best way to do it. And constantly run `/clear @p crafting_table` so that nobody can have crafting tables.

Comment: @MINEMortal you should not use villagers,  you could just use two items for a "crafted" Item! You should use Container like chest/ender-chest... and check where the play put what item (not 100% sure if it works with out mod)

Answer (score 6):

You can set the gamerule `doLimitedCrafting`:

```
/gamerule doLimitedCrafting true
```

That prevents everyone from crafting anything for which they haven't unlocked the recipe yet.
To allow them everything by default, do this:

```
/recipe give @a *
```

Then take away all the recipes you want to become impossible:

```
/recipe take @a <name>
```

with `<name>` being the recipe's name, which you can easily get with autocomplete.

Comment: I completely rewrote your answer, I hope you're ok with that. If not, just edit it. It's now a complete solution with commands and explanation instead of just a rough idea.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to `/testfor` the items you want to disable in the player's inventory, `/clear` them, then `/give` back the items that were used to make it. *I'm 90% sure it's possible.*

Comment: I might have to do that, but I'd rather not, sorry!

Comment: Consider this: Player needs gold block to complete mission. When player gets gold block, it is decrafted into gold ingots, and then into nuggets. Now, the challenge is broken. Nice idea, though!

Answer (score -3):

Just do
`/gamerule doLimitedCrafting true`
and
`/clear @a @a`

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Arqade! Could you provide more information on what these commands do, and how they would be useful to the asker?